# How to grow block menu on hover

Tags: routes, javascript

I am trying to make secondary menu grow on mouse hover. just like this [site](http://www.pullandbear.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/home/pullandbearid/en/pullandbear)

we can see on the bottom of the page. menu block can grow bigger and show more menu.

any idea what technique used to make something like that. or maybe a module or maybe jQuery. right now i'm still googling but still got no clues.
Please let me know some idea about this.

Regards

mbahlol
pardon for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle that will show 3 different techniques. http://jsfiddle.net/3rYCs/

Comment: thank you for showing me that techniques. now i can try it to my block menu.

Answer (score 0):

I just set up something very similar on my site using the TB Menu module - https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu